# Reducer typings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I can not understand how to deal with new typings of Redux.
Right now i am trying to complete this tutorial https://maxfarseer.gitbooks.io/redux-course-ru/content/index.html

At this moment I am on "Creating Store" phase with this simple code below:
store/configureStore.ts

```
import {createStore, Reducer} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState);

    if (module.hot) {
        module.hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
            const nextRootReducer=require('../reducers');
            store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
        })
    }

    return store;
}
```

When I try to compile it messages me about this error:

```
 ERROR in ./src/store/configureStore.ts
    (10,34): error TS2345: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type '<A extends Action>(state: any, action: A) => any'.
      Type '{}' provides no match for the signature '<A extends Action>(state: any, action: A): any'
```

This is my index file of reducers

```
import {combineReducers} from "redux/index";
import page from './page';
import user from './user';

    const rootReducer = combineReducers({
        page,
        user
    });

    export default rootReducer;

//page.ts
const initialState = {
    year: 2016,
    photos: []
};

function page(state = initialState,
              action = {type: '', payload: null}) {
    return state
}

export default page;

//user.ts
const initialState = {
    name: 'Аноним'
};

export default function user(state = initialState,
                                action = {type: '', payload: null}) {
    return state
}
```

Comment: It looks like hot reloading is throwing some empty objects in there when it does the hot reloads somehow and this is throwing an type error by typescript

Comment: `import rootReducer from '../reducers';`

`const nextRootReducer = require('../reducers');`
I am not sure about this parts. Is this a valid typescript?

Comment: https://github.com/jaysoo/todomvc-redux-react-typescript/blob/master/client/main/reducer.ts Check this example, looks like you're following what  hes doing

Comment: Almost but he uses old typings of redux and no hmr.
In purpose of learn i wanted to enable hrm with typescript. But i feel that i a missing something

Comment: Why do you have multiple default exports in your reducers file?

Comment: I don't have. It's separated files, I showed it in comments.